# Salesforce PickList to dynamic hyperlinks list

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

In Salesforce Classic or alternative deployments what capabilities does a user have to be able to display the arbitrary list of PickList items as HyperLinks to filtered reports for example?  Is this possible in vanilla Salesforce or is Apex/VisualForce necessary to complete such a capability?

Once the custom field has been added to an object, how can we display the list that is generated in the detail view as clickable-links?  The editable view shoudl remain as Standard PickList.

Here is a screenshot displaying the selections within the detail view:

[image: screenshot displaying the selections within the detail view]

How can this list be displayed as a list of hyperlinks?
Essentially how can one easily iterate through the recorded PickList items and use the values to create a display of HyperLnks of dynamic length dependent upon the number of items "picked".

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible without using Apex / Visualforce.

I recommend creating a formula field that uses the PickList value to build the URL and display it with the HYPERLINK formula method.

That would display a clickable link in Salesforce Classic and Lightning.

Comment: Tiaan Swatt : Could you please help how this can be achieved with one example, that would be a great help.